# PYPY installation for dummies - What to do with the zip file

Tags: python, installation, pypy

I'm trying to use Pypy to make my code run faster, but I don't know what to do with the zip file I downloaded from the site (I tried to read the directions but it moves too fast and I don't know what's going on). I was wondering if anyone had simple step by step instructions on how to install and use Pypy. Also, Im using Wing on Windows

Answer (score 13):

Unzip the zip file to a suitable location, e.g. `C:\pypy` then run `pypy.exe` from the folder to which you unzipped. There is no installation for pypy. Similarly to uninstall just delete the folder.

Running `C:\pypy\pypy.exe` gives you an interactive prompt, just like the one you get for running any other version of Python except it uses four chevrons `>>>>`.

To run a script with pypy you can explicitly name the interpreter:

```
C:\pypy\pypy.exe script.py
```

Or, if you have Python 3.3 installed on the same system, you can use the Windows Python launcher. Edit the ini file (%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\py.ini) with %USERPROFILE% replaced by your home folder name to contain:

```
[commands]
pypy=c:\pypy\pypy.exe
```

Then you can simply put a hashbang line at the start of any script and it will automatically run pypy when you run the script from a command line e.g. `script.py`, or when you click on its icon:

```
#!pypy
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

or use `#!python27` to make a script run with Python 2.7, or `#!python33` to make it run with Python 3.3.

Comment: Ohh I see. thanks for that. Now it has a prompt but I dont know what to do!

Comment: I've expanded my answer, hope this helps.